# An asp:UpdatePanel is stopping the download pop up to pop up

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a program that generates and then downloads an excel file. I have my html code in an asp:UpdatePanel. However, when I click on btnExportDetailsbutton the loading from the update panel is stopping the popup for the download. I have tried the

```
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportDetails" />
    </Triggers>
```

but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to get both the UpdatePanel to work and also have the download pop up aswell?

This is the logic in my GetExcel() that generates the file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteBuffer.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=rpt" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(byteBuffer);
Response.End();
```

This is my html logic for the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExportDetails" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View0" runat="server">
```

This is what my button is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportDetails" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" Width="125" 
OnClick="btnExportDetails_Click" />
```

Also, I'm using a Web form with Master page so I don't have a <body? tag. I say that because some solutions say to place the trigger right below the  tag but in this situation I don't have one.

Comment: Your code works fine. My guess would be that there is some error in front-end javascript or `btnExportDetails_Click`. Start by checking the Browser Console for errors in the Console or Network tab.

Comment: I agree, in theory it should work. I'll do what you suggested and dig deeper into finding the root cause of the problem. Thank you for your help!